# Отправить данные из БД на почту

Tags: php, mysql, sendmail

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно отправить данные из БД на почту в виде html.
Вывожу данные из БД следующим образом

```
$query3 ="SELECT * FROM users";

$resultc = mysqli_query($link, $query3) or die("Ошибка " . 
mysqli_error($link)); 
if($resultc)
{
$rowsu = mysqli_num_rows($resultc); // количество полученных строк

echo "<br><br><form action='send.php' method='post'><table table 
class='table table-bordered table-hover' name='zayavka'><tr><th>Column1</th> 
<th>Column2</th><th>Column3</th><th>Column4</th> 
<th>Column5</th><th>Column6</th><th>Column7</th> 
<th>Column8</th><th>Column9</th></tr>";
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $rowsu ; ++$i)
{
    $rowu = mysqli_fetch_row($resultc);
    echo "<tr>";
        for ($j = 0 ; $j < 9 ; ++$j) echo "<td>$rowu[$j]</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'> </form>";



// очищаем результат
mysqli_free_result($resultc);   

// закрываем подключение
mysqli_close($link); 
}
```

Как полученные данные отправить на почту. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: [Прежде чем задать вопрос, убедитесь, что вы выполнили тщательный поиск ответа. Поделитесь результатом вашего поиска и расскажите, что вы нашли и почему найденные ответы вас не устроили. Это продемонстрирует вашу способность думать самостоятельно, поможет избежать повторяющихся очевидных ответов и, самое важное, увеличит шансы на получение точного ответа!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query3 ="SELECT * FROM users";

$resultc = mysqli_query($link, $query3) or die("Ошибка " . 
mysqli_error($link)); 
if($resultc)
{
$rowsu = mysqli_num_rows($resultc); // количество полученных строк
ob_start();
echo "<br><br><form action='send.php' method='post'><table table 
class='table table-bordered table-hover' name='zayavka'><tr><th>Column1</th> 
<th>Column2</th><th>Column3</th><th>Column4</th> 
<th>Column5</th><th>Column6</th><th>Column7</th> 
<th>Column8</th><th>Column9</th></tr>";
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $rowsu ; ++$i)
{
    $rowu = mysqli_fetch_row($resultc);
    echo "<tr>";
        for ($j = 0 ; $j < 9 ; ++$j) echo "<td>$rowu[$j]</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'> </form>";

$out1 = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
mail('email@email.com', 'My Subject', $out1);
// очищаем результат
mysqli_free_result($resultc);   

// закрываем подключение
mysqli_close($link); 
}
```

только почту замените на свою